# Get 1st level in ForEach Object in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

This line in PowerShell "Get-ChildItem $workingDir -Recurse" gives  me below  output

2020-12-06T10:51:08.4016796Z d-----        12/6/2020  10:50 AM                _DevOpsScripts
2020-12-06T10:51:08.4024837Z d-----        12/6/2020  10:50 AM                _test1-pattern
2020-12-06T10:51:08.4032732Z d-----        12/6/2020  10:50 AM                _test_iver
2020-12-06T10:51:08.4040550Z d-----        12/6/2020  10:50 AM                _Licenses
2020-12-06T10:51:08.4048759Z d-----        12/6/2020  10:51 AM                test_folder
2020-12-06T10:51:08.4057205Z d-----        12/6/2020  10:50 AM                readme.txt

These are files and folder in $workingDir which is System.DefaultWorkingDirectory.

IF i modify the above code to

```
`Get-ChildItem $workingDir -Recurse | ForEach-Object {`   
    
    Write-Host $_.FullName
    
    }
```

I get all the files inside my above folders. that is I get files inside my DevOps artifacts and so on. I do not want that, I am just looking to loop at the first level, as I need to create a zip for each. How do I do a foreach to get only the first level inside my $workingDir? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using recurse if you only want the first level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Parent -Depth 1 - Recurse

Where Depth is :
The Depth parameter determines the number of subdirectory levels to include in the recursion.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: This should be just `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Parent`. Parameter `-Depth` has effect only when `-Recurse` is used.

Comment: yes without recurse and depth works..thanks